# starting browser and passing data to it from winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform app that needs to open a URL in a new browser window and pass data to it. Also the data is too large to pass through query string parameters.
Is there a way to start a new browser instance and pass the data as form data or session somehow?

Comment: What is the data? What is receiving it?

Comment: Just curious, what kind of data are you trying to pass, maybe there is an alternate route, i.e. going directly to your data store, secondly, do you have control over the website/application you intend to launch?

Comment: The data is an xml representation of an object, an industry standard representation. The winform app has all knowledge of the object. The website is used to generate correspondence and uses the properties of the object, however, it doesn't have any knowledge of where the object comes from. And there is no shared data store. I was hoping to be able to use something like process.start or httpwebrequest, but so far no luck.

Comment: Great question @jsp, we too have the same damn problem and would love to find a solution. I'm surprised that in 'embedded' mode, IE wouldn't support something.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer to your question, but you can embed an IE control in your window and handle it easy from your code.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control over the website you're sending to, I'd go with RandomNoobs suggestion.
Pass the data into your data store with an unique id for that data. Pass that id in the querystring, and you can get the data with the unique id from the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will help, but here's how I would go for it.

1. Build your parameters, and store them into a paramter data table that would be used to get the parameters from, from your web browser's page;
2. Launch your browser and pass some parameters values, either an Id or something that could be used to identify your full parameters to query for against the underlying database;
3. From your webpage opened in your browser, collect the value to use to query against the parameter table, and query it;
4. Retrieve the parameters and perform the desired work for your Session.

**EDIT #1**

If this is an XML representation, just save this XML representation into an XML file and place it into a shared disk storage so that you may open the file and read it from your web application.

Perhaps [`Serialization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.runtime.serialization.aspx) could be useful here.

Hope this helps! =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the database to store your object

Answer (score 0):

1) store your object via your persistence method of choice (most likely a SQL database)

2) retrieve the key that uniquely identifies that object in the database (probably the primary key, be it an auto-incrementing integer or a GUID)

3) pass that key to the webpage via query string

4) have the page load that object from your database.

5) ...?

6) Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Link  = "http://aaa.com/asdas.exe" for example. you can use like this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

   p.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + Link + "\"";
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   p.Start();
```