# How can you set the value of a textbox on a webpage from a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I'm developing an internal .NET WinForms tool which can launch IE to a specific internal website. I'd like to be able to automatically set the values of the username / password textboxes in the browser, but I don't know if this is possible.

I do know the control names as I have access to the source code for that web application, but I can't seem to find any examples of how to interact with an independent browser control like that.

Something like

`Process.Start("mywebsite.com/login.aspx?uname=" + txtUN.Text + "&pw=" + txtPW.Text);`

But since the web app isn't really expecting any parameters in the URL it's not going to do anything with that.

Something similar to this, I guess :

[starting browser and passing data to it from winform application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187331/starting-browser-and-passing-data-to-it-from-winform-application)

But that question has no accepted solution, and while I have *access* to the source code this isn't something I can change really. So if there's a way to do it without modifying the web application, that'd be great.

Comment: Short of using a `WebBrowser` control in your application, you'd need to interact with the browser instance itself.  There's no mechanism just in *launching* the browser to accomplish this.  It looks like Internet Explorer has some integration you can use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  For other browsers, you'd need to find something similar.  Perhaps using an automated browser testing tool (such as WatiN) would work for this.

Comment: @David Thanks for the idea. "Luckily", IE is required for this site so that makes it a little easier. But using a WebBrowser control for this isn't practical unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at browser automation libraries like [WatiN](http://watin.org/) or [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu) that automate the browser application itself, accessing the controls by their name.

This reminds me also of [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) but it is Java based and last i checked it has no .Net bindings.